# Spring ContextConfiguration with Maven dependency

Tags: java, spring, maven, configuration

for now to run Spring context in my project I must use:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = GlobalConfig.class)
```

on one of files.

I'm wondering :

Can i setup this value in maven configuration?

If yes how?

Can't find information or looking in wrong way :(

Thanks for help

Comment: Why do you want to do something like that?

Comment: `@ContextConfiguration` is a test class you shouldn't use that in your main program.

Comment: @M. Deinum  Im using it in Project with  tests,  which  is in src/test.

Comment: Why would you want to make this configurable in Maven. The configuration to load is bound to the test, why would you need to pass that in from maven?

Comment: As my project is test project :), I dont want have @ ContextConfiguration above some class if It is possible to have it in maven.
From that I know from developers in company it is not imposible.
Thanks @M.Deinum for help!